# How define field in my ( class) as primary key and use it to browse the records between views in Odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

**Please, I am beginner in python my question is how define field in my table (class) as primary key and use it to browse the records between views.**

Exemple :

How to define **NumOffre** as primary key and use it later between views

```
enter code here
class saisirsoum(osv.osv):
_name='saisir.soum' 

_columns = {
    'NumOffre' : fields.char('N° Offre'), # to be defined as primary key !!
    'organisme_s' : fields.char('Organisme'),
    'des_offre' : fields.char('Designation'),
    'order_line' : fields.one2many('saisir.soumission.ligne','order_id','soumission_id'),
    'observation_d' : fields.text('Observation'),
    }
```

Comment: you can use sql_constraint in odoo so thsi filed is work as a primary key.

Comment: How add sql contraint ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put this way to unique NumOffre

```
_sql_constraints = [
    ('Num_Offre', 'unique(NumOffre)', 'Offre Number must be unique!'),
]
```

Comment: il always takes two record the same keys